# Is it OK to include someone else's info?

Tags: discussion, support

Is it OK for me to use ideas from someone else's answer in mine? For example, if I post an answer, and someone else posts an answer or comment with an additional idea, can I incorporate their idea into my answer?

Comment: I frequently link other answers, but would never paste someone else's work into mine. I tend to regard this as an attempt to get credit for someone else's answer. If an answer would exclusively refer to someone else's post, then it should be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, if it complements or completes your answer (so it's not just a rip-off but really an organic addition to what you are saying). Make sure you give them credit for the idea.  I tend to do something like

> A general way to achieve this is xyz. (Or, as [@username says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207085/138112), you could do abc.)

Answer (score 9):

It's important to remember that one of the main ideas behind Stack Overflow is that it becomes a general repository of quality questions and answers. This is the reasoning behind a lot of how the site is designed, from being able to edit (almost) anybody’s posts to community moderation. As such it is entirely OK, and I would say even encouraged to include information from someone else.

In short as [@probably Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112/probably-pekka) says yes as long as it an organic addition to what your saying and you make sure to credit them...

Comment: +1 for such an nice meta-answer (and on `meta`, no less ;-) )

Comment: It's too minor to propose an edit, but the spell is [so] ;)

Comment: @brasofilo Updated, I always though the site name was without the space, but it looks like your right and it is with a space.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the link in my previous comment results from the magic link `[so]`. Yep, me too, I only realized it was separated after seeing some edits here in Meta.